# Typo3 get parameters from link-wizard

Tags: typo3, fluid, viewhelper

I have a link-wizard in my fluid template to let the user select a page or an external link in the T3-tree.

```
<flux:field.input name="myLink" label="Select-Link">
    <flux:wizard.link/>
</flux:field.input>
```

This ends up in a DB-entry that looks like this:

```
http://example.com _blank link-class link-title
```

How do I extract the target, class and link-title using a view-helper (or any other means)?

I tried using {myLink.parameter.extTarget} or {myLink.extTarget} - nothing works.

Is there a way to get these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this refers to to some Frontend input/output.

First, i would do some `<f:debug inline="1">mylink</f:debug>`to see if any output is available at all.

In General, If you want to access your DB values in Fluid, you need an Extension which provides you with the corresponding Doman/Model and Domain/Repository

You will end up with something like this:

```
<?php
linkspace MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Model;

class Whatever {

    /**
    * @var string The link of whatever
    */
    protected $link;

    public function setLink($link) {
        $this->link = $link;
    }

    public function getLink() {
        return $this->link;
    }
}
```

When your ext is working, you should be able to access your values via fluid with no viewhelper at all.

Have a look at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/5-Domain/2-implementing-the-domain-model.html - this will provide you with the some information on this topic.

Comment: Doesn't sound as easy as I'd like it to be, but I guess that'll work... thanks!

Comment: I, too, had some headaches wrapping my brain around that... but the concept is pretty solid and works pretty well when you'r into it.